# push to heroku problems: sqlite / gems / bundler

Tags: heroku

i got a really big problem. Just started learning ruby - everything is fine. But no searching for hours to find a solution to push on heroku. but no luck. please help me,  (unfortunately on a Win7)
thanks a lot:

```
C:\Sites\code\omrails>git push heroku master
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.154' to the
 list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/mdz/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 26.54 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 69 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> WARNING: Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Installing rake (10.0.4)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.6)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.13)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.13)
       Installing mime-types (1.23)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.14)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.13)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.13)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.13)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (3.2.13)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.1)
       Installing rails (3.2.13)
       Installing sass (3.2.9)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex
tension.
       /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (
the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
       necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
       details.  You may need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2bxzg0nyav6hg/vendor/bundle
/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_2bxzg0nyav6hg/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/
sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use SQLite on Heroku, you'll have to use PostgreSQL. You can set it up to use PostgreSQL on Heroku but SQLite in development by putting the `pg` gem in a `production` group in your Gemfile, and `sqlite` in a `development` group, but Heroku recommends you use the same database in both your development and production environments.