# Failing to push to heroku using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm unable to push my app to heroku whilst using rails.
I get this error message saying:

```
An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundling.
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !     
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Here's the code on my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 3.0.0.0'
gem 'devise'
group :development do
  gem 'rails_layout'
end
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Please don't ask questions on "how to solve [an] error" if **the error tells you how to solve it**.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been answered many times.
[push to heroku problems: sqlite / gems / bundler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077401/push-to-heroku-problems-sqlite-gems-bundler)

> You can't use SQLite on Heroku, you'll have to use PostgreSQL. You can set it up to use PostgreSQL on Heroku but SQLite in development by putting the `pg` gem in a `production` group in your Gemfile, and `sqlite` in a `development` group, but Heroku recommends you use the same database in both your development and production environments.

The reason of the error is also explained in the Heroku error message, with a documentation link that you are supposed to read to fix the issue.

There is also a brand new article about using Rails on Heroku that provides additional info on [switching from SQLite to PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#use-postgres).

Comment: I did that and I followed the heroku documentation as well but it didn't work. what should i do?

Comment: As explained, you must switch to PostgreSQL because Heroku does not support SQLite. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#use-postgres

Comment: did you not read my comment?

Comment: I did, but I can't see any evidence in your Gemfile that you actually switched your application to PostgreSQL. I still see the sqlite gem. Please carefully read the 3 articles I referenced, they all contain the solution to your issue.

Comment: Thanks. waiting 20 mins to upload my next question that contain all the evidence. no contention pursued. i checked all 3 and none worked for me, so this seems like a unique situation.

Comment: Update this one, instead of creating a new question.