# Heroku: Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sqlite

I have been stuck for a week trying to figure this out. I have currently been following online lectures, however I followed everything exactly, and the instructor isn't really of any help. Whenever I try to push to heroku I receive the following:

> Initializing repository, done.
>       Counting objects: 85, done.
>       Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
>       Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
>       Writing objects: 100% (85/85), 27.36 KiB, done.
>       Total 85 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> ```
> -----> Ruby app detected
> -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
> -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
> -----> Warning:
>        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
>        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
>        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
>        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies
>  all.
>        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
> -----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.5.2
>        New app detected loading default bundler cache
>        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundl
> -binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
>        Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3 (>= 0) more than once.
>        You should probably keep only one of them.
>        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the
> sion of just one of them later.
>        Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3 (>= 0) more than once.
>        You should probably keep only one of them.
>        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the
> sion of just one of them later.
>        Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (= 2.6.1) more than once.
>        You should probably keep only one of them.
>        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the
> sion of just one of them later.
>        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
>        Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
>        Resolving dependencies...
>        Using builder (3.0.4)
>        Using erubis (2.7.0)
>        Using journey (1.0.4)
>        Using rack (1.4.5)
>        Using hike (1.2.3)
>        Using tilt (1.4.1)
>        Installing i18n (0.6.1)
>        Using polyglot (0.3.3)
>        Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
>        Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
>        Using bundler (1.5.2)
>        Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
>        Using execjs (2.0.2)
>        Using json (1.8.1)
>        Using thor (0.18.1)
>        Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
>        Installing rake (10.1.1)
>        Installing arel (3.0.3)
>        Using rack-cache (1.2)
>        Using rack-test (0.6.2)
>        Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
>        Using treetop (1.4.15)
>        Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
>        Using rdoc (3.12.2)
>        Installing sass (3.2.13)
>        Installing uglifier (2.4.0)
>        Using sprockets (2.2.2)
>        Using mail (2.5.4)
>        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
> tension.
>        /tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-428ba3caf9e0/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/
> y extconf.rb
>        checking for sqlite3.h... no
>        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
>        or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search pat
> the
>        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
>        *** extconf.rb failed ***
>        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessa
>        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
>  may
>        need configuration options.
>        Provided configuration options:
>        --with-opt-dir
>        --without-opt-dir
>        --with-opt-include
>        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>        --with-opt-lib
>        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>        --with-make-prog
>        --without-make-prog
>        --srcdir=.
>        --curdir
>        --ruby=/tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-428ba3caf9e0/vendor/ruby-2.0
> bin/ruby
>        --with-sqlite3-dir
>        --without-sqlite3-dir
>        --with-sqlite3-include
>        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>        --with-sqlite3-lib
>        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
>        --enable-local
>        --disable-local
>        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-
> ba3caf9e0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
>        Results logged to /tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-428ba3caf9e0/vend
> bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
>        Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
>        Installing pg (0.17.1)
>        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot
> ntinue.
>        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundli
>
>        Bundler Output: Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3 (>= 0) more than on
>
>        You should probably keep only one of them.
>        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the
> sion of just one of them later.
>        Your Gemfile lists the gem sqlite3 (>= 0) more than once.
>        You should probably keep only one of them.
>        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the
> sion of just one of them later.
>        Your Gemfile lists the gem rspec-rails (= 2.6.1) more than once.
>        You should probably keep only one of them.
>        While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the
> sion of just one of them later.
>        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
>        Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
>        Resolving dependencies...
>        Using builder (3.0.4)
>        Using erubis (2.7.0)
>        Using journey (1.0.4)
>        Using rack (1.4.5)
>        Using hike (1.2.3)
>        Using tilt (1.4.1)
>        Installing i18n (0.6.1)
>        Using polyglot (0.3.3)
>        Installing mime-types (1.25.1)
>        Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
>        Using bundler (1.5.2)
>        Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
>        Using execjs (2.0.2)
>        Using json (1.8.1)
>        Using thor (0.18.1)
>        Installing multi_json (1.8.4)
>        Installing rake (10.1.1)
>        Installing arel (3.0.3)
>        Using rack-cache (1.2)
>        Using rack-test (0.6.2)
>        Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
>        Using treetop (1.4.15)
>        Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
>        Using rdoc (3.12.2)
>        Installing sass (3.2.13)
>        Installing uglifier (2.4.0)
>        Using sprockets (2.2.2)
>        Using mail (2.5.4)
>
>        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native
> tension.
>
>        /tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-428ba3caf9e0/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/
> y extconf.rb
>        checking for sqlite3.h... no
>        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
>        or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search pat
> the
>        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
>        *** extconf.rb failed ***
>        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessa
>        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.
>  may
>        need configuration options.
>
>        Provided configuration options:
>        --with-opt-dir
>        --without-opt-dir
>        --with-opt-include
>        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>        --with-opt-lib
>        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>        --with-make-prog
>        --without-make-prog
>        --srcdir=.
>        --curdir
>        --ruby=/tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-428ba3caf9e0/vendor/ruby-2.0
> bin/ruby
>        --with-sqlite3-dir
>        --without-sqlite3-dir
>        --with-sqlite3-include
>        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>        --with-sqlite3-lib
>        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
>        --enable-local
>        --disable-local
>
>
>        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-
> ba3caf9e0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8 for inspection.
>        Results logged to /tmp/build_903734dc-f591-44eb-8891-428ba3caf9e0/vend
> bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
>        Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
>        Installing pg (0.17.1)
>        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.8), and Bundler cannot
> ntinue.
>        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.8'` succeeds before bundli
>
>  !
>  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
>  !
>  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
>  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
>  !
>
>  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
>
> To git@heroku.com:tranquil-ridge-7489.git
>  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:tranquil-ridge-7489.git'
> ```

I have tried rebuilding the gem files, deleting gemfile.lock and running bundle installer, following solution from previous questions, but I am still getting this error.

Here is my current gemFile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'

group :development do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1', :require => 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1', :require => 'rpec-rails'
    gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
    gem 'turn', :require => false
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg'
end
```

Any help on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [push to heroku problems: sqlite / gems / bundler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077401/push-to-heroku-problems-sqlite-gems-bundler)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend a few things:

1) Follow the instructions [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile) to deal with the *Gemfile* issues that arise when deploying a Ruby project generated on Windows.

2) Do the following in your Gemfile

```
group :test, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

This gets rid of `sqlite3` from your production deployment. Use it for unit and integration testing, but use PostgreSQL for acceptance/functional testing because that's the RDBMS of choice on Heroku. Also, reference your gems only once each.

3) Set up the [Hobby Dev version of the PostgreSQL add-on](https://addons.heroku.com/heroku-postgresql) in your deployment environment on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

[You can't use SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3), you'll have to use PostgreSQL.

You can set it up to use PostgreSQL on Heroku but SQLite in development, it's a good practice to use the same database in both your development and production environments.

Notice that you list the `gem 'sqlite3'` multiple times, including one outside the development group. This causes Heroku to try to install it.

My suggestion is to remove the `sqlite` gem completely and switch all to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

remove the top `gem sqlite3` and add  `ruby '2.0.0'` at the top of your gemfile

also under the group production add `gem 'rails_12factor'`